# Printing page from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I wrote a simple generator to create offers. It works good, but I got the problem with printing. When I try a print page from AJAX request, I getting index page not data from AJAX request.

**What's wrong?**

**Additionally, data from AJAX is correct.**

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "generate.php",
    data: {pid: pid, net: net, brutto: brutto, contractor: contractor, delivery: delivery, term: term},
}).done(function(data) {
    window.print(data);
});
```

**Example for PHP file :**

```
<?php
$foo = "foo";
ob_start();
?>

<p><?php echo $foo; ?></p>

<?php 

$result = ob_get_flush();
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `print()` method doesn't take any arguments. So, if you want to print data from variable, you can use this method:

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "generate.php",
    data: {pid: pid, net: net, brutto: brutto, contractor: contractor, delivery: delivery, term: term},
}).done(function(data) {
    printWindow = window.open('');
    printWindow.document.write(data);
    printWindow.print();
});
```

this will open a new tab, with value of `data` on screen and ready to print.

Comment: This didnt work for me - The tab didnt open. I got a blank page...

Comment: @RaulChiarella please check the console for any errors, like maybe you don't have jquery if you are trying to run $.post or something, and just to make sure run this piece of code to make sure that the print part is working `data='TEST';printWindow = window.open(''); printWindow.document.write(data); printWindow.print();`

Answer (score 3):

The [`print()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print):

> Opens the Print Dialog to print the current document.

It doesn't take any arguments (so any arguments you pass it will be ignored).

If you want to print data you have in a variable, you need to put it in the document the user is viewing.